# How to find and remove first/starting string from an Arabic string having diacritics but maintaining the original diacritics of remaining string

Tags: javascript, regex, comparison, locale, arabic

The aim is to find and remove a starting string/chars/word from an Arabic string that we don't know if it has diacritics or not **but must maintain any and all diacritics of the remaining string (if any)**.

There are many answers for removing the first/starting string/chars from an English string on StackOverflow, but there is no existing solution to this problem found on StackOverflow that maintains the balance of the Arabic string in its original form.

If the original string is normalized (removing the diacritics, tanween, etc.) before processing it, then the remaining string returned will be the balance of the normalized string, not the remaining of the original string.

Example. Assume the following original string which can be in any of the following forms (i.e. the same string but different diacritics):

## **1. "السلام عليكم ورحمة الله"**

## **2. "السَلام عليكمُ ورحمةُ الله"**

## **3. "السَلامُ عَليكمُ ورَحمةُ الله"**

## **4. "السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله"**

Now let us say we want to remove the first/staring characters "السلام" only if the string starts with such characters (which it does), and return the remaining of the "**original**" string **with its original diacritics**.

Of course, we are looking for the characters "السلام" without diacritics because we don't know how the original string is formatted with diacritics.

So, in this case, the returned remaining of each string must be:

## **1. " عليكم ورحمة الله"**

## **2. " عليكمُ ورحمةُ الله"**

## **3. " عَليكمُ ورَحمةُ الله"**

## **4. " عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله"**

The following code works for an English string (there are many other solutions) but not for an Arabic string as explained above.

```js
function removeStartWord(string,word) {
if (string.startsWith(word)) string=string.slice(word.length);
return string;
}
```

The above code uses the principle of slicing the starting characters found from the original string based on the characters' length; which works fine for English text.

For an Arabic string, we don't know the form of diacritics of the original string and thus the length of the string/characters we are looking for in the original string will be different and unknown.

**Edit: Added example image for better clarifications.**

The following image table provides further examples:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you calling *"balance"* of a string? It's not a concept typically associated with strings and it would be good to know what you mean. Can you describe it in more technical detail?

Comment: The `balance` of the string is the `remaining part` of the string after removing the matching starting characters from it.

Comment: FYI, everybody else calls that the *remainder*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep track of the discussion, I'm adding a new answer,
try this please!

```js
function removeStartWord(string, word) {
  const alphabeticString =  string.replace(/[^a-zA-Zء-ي0-9/]+/g, '');
  if(!alphabeticString.startsWith(word)) return string;
  const letters = [...word];
  let cleanString = '';
  string.split('').forEach((_letter) => {
    if(letters.indexOf(_letter) > -1) {
      delete letters[letters.indexOf(_letter)]
    }else{
      cleanString += _letter;
    }
  });
  return cleanString.replace(/[^a-zA-Zء-ي0-9/\s]*/i, '');
}

const sampleData = `السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`;

console.log('sampleData ...', sampleData);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'الس') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'الس')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام ') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام ')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, ' السلام') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, ' السلام')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is indeed very good and very close. There is one issue though: it removes the diacritics of the first character of the remaining string. For example, if you ask to remove the letters "ال" from the word "السَّلَامُ" it will return the word "سلَامُ" i.e. without فتحة و شدة (fatha and shaddah) on the letter "s" سين. It should return "سَّلَامُ" not "سلَامُ".

Comment: The function will also incorrectly remove the space if the string has no diacritics. Try to remove the word: `"ال"` from the start of the string: `"السيد جعفر"`. It will give the output `"سيدجعفر"` removing the space which is incorrect.

Comment: edited to fix the space issue, and still thinking about first diacritic

Comment: check if it keep the first diacritic now, please!

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I will do some further tests.

Comment: I suggest that you also add code to ignore the tahmeez (همزة الألِف) so that you can remove the characters even if it starts with "ألسلام"

Comment: problem is that "أ" is a letter by itself, not  "ا" + "ء"

Comment: Thanks Jafar. Your solution is great and I will try to improve it to solve the tahmeez issue.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241305/arabic-javascript

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei ... There is still an issue with how trailing/leading whitespace of the search string gets handled, right now it doesn't replace/remove such strings.

Comment: @JafarJabr The function cannot remove a leading space if the look-for string is a space.

Comment: @Mohsen Alyafei a test case please!

Comment: @PeterSeliger I agree this needs to be improved to handle the trailing/leading whitespace of the search string.

Comment: @JafarJabr try to remove the letters `" ال"`  from the start of the string " السلام". Both the source string and the search string start with a whitespace. Also, try to remove the string `"السلام "`  from the start of the string "السلام عليكم". Both the source string and the search string end with whitespace.

Comment: @JafarJabr possible solution added.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with the following as a possible solution.

The following solution is broken into 2 parts; firstly the function `startsWithAr()` is used to "partially" mimic the javascript `startsWith()` method but for an Arabic string.

However instead of returning `'true'` or `'false'`, it will return the `index after the characters we are looking for` at the start of the Source String (i.e. the length of the string found in the Source String including its Tashkeel (diacritics) if any), otherwise, it returns `-1` if the characters of the specified string are not found at the start of the string.

Using the `startsWithAr()` function, we then create (in the **2nd part**) a function that removes the characters of the specified string if found at the start of the Source String using the `slice()` method; the `removeStartString()` function.

This approach permits not only maintaining the Tashkeel (diacritics) of the remainder of the Source String but also allows strings with Tahmeez to be searched and removed.

The function ignores Tashkeel (diacritics) and Tahmeez in **both** the Source String and the Look-For Search strings and will return the remaining part of the Source String with its original Tashkeel (diacritics) intact after removing the specified staring of characters from the beginning of the Source String.

This way we can use the function to handle all Unicode in the Arabic script not limit it to a defined range because any other characters of whatever language are ignored.

We can also improve it easily by matching "ه" with "ة" so we can remove the string "السيدة" even if it is written as "السيده" by adding `.replace(/[ة]/g,'ه')` at the 2 `.replace()` lines.

I have included below separate test cases on the use of the `startsWithAr()` function and the `removeStartString()` functions.

The two functions can be combined into one function if needed.

Please improve as necessary; any suggestions are appreciated.

---

## 1st Part: startsWithAr()

---

```js
//=====================================================================
// startsWithAr() function
// Purpose:
// Determines whether an Arabic string (the "Source String") begins with the characters
// of a specified string (the "Look-For String").
// Return the position (index) after the Look-For String if found, else return -1 if not found.
// Ignores Tashkeel (diacritics) and Tahmeez in both the Source and Look-For Strings.
// The returned position index is zero based.
// By knowing the position (index) after the Look-For String, one can remove the
// starting string using the slice() method while maintaining the remainder of the Source String with
// its original tashkeel (diacritics) unchanged.
//
// Parameters:
// str     : The Source String to search in.
// lookFor : The characters to be searched for at the start of this string.
//=====================================================================
function startsWithAr(str,lookFor) {
let indexLookFor=0, tshk=/[ؐ-ًؕ-ٖٓ-ٟۖ-ٰٰۭـ]/, w=/[ؤ]/g,hamz=/[آأإٱٲٳٵ]/g;
lookFor=lookFor.replace(hamz,'ا').replace(w,'و').replace(/[ؐ-ًؕ-ٖٓ-ٟۖ-ٰٰۭـ]/g,''); // normalize the lookFor string
for (let indexStr=0; indexStr<str.length;indexStr++) {
while(tshk.test(str[indexStr])&&indexStr<str.length)++indexStr; // skip tashkeel & increase index
if (lookFor[indexLookFor]!==str[indexStr].replace(hamz,'ا').replace(w,'و')) return-1; // no match, so exit -1
indexLookFor++;                               // match found so next char in lookFor String
    if (indexLookFor>=lookFor.length) {       // if end of Source String then WE FOUND IT
      indexStr+=1;                            // point after source char
      while(tshk.test(str[indexStr])&&indexStr<str.length)++indexStr; // skip tashkeel after Source String if any
    return indexStr;      // return index in Source String after lookFor string and after any tashkeel
    }
}
return-1; // not found end of string reached
}
//=========================================
// test cases for startsWithAr() function
//=========================================
var r =0; // test tracking flag
r |= test("السلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","السلام",6);  // find the start letters 'السلام'
r |= test("الْسًّلامُ عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","السلام",10); // find the start letters 'السلام'
r |= test("الْسًّلامُ عَلَيَكُمُ وَرَحَمَةَ الله","السَّلام",10); // find the start letters 'السَّلام'
r |= test("ألْسًّلامُ عَلَيَكُمُ وَرَحَمَةَ الله","السَّلام",10); // find the start letters 'السَّلام'
r |= test("السؤال هو التالي","السوال",6);      // find the start letters 'السوال'
r |= test("السيد/علي","السيد",5);           // find the start letters 'السيد'
r |= test("السيد/علي","ف",-1);           // find the start letters 'السيد'
r |= test(" السيد"," ",1);               // find the start letter ' ' (space)
r |= test("المجد لنا","ال",2);             // find the start letters 'ال'
r |= test("المجد لنا","ا",1);              // find the start letter  'ا'
r |= test("ألمجد لنا","ال",2);             // find the start letters 'ال'
r |= test("إلمجد لنا","ال",2);             // find the start letters 'ال'
r |= test("إلمجد لنا","ألْ",2);             // find the start letters 'ألْ'
r |= test("إلْمَجد لَنا","ألْ",3);             // find the start letters 'ألْ'
r |= test("","ا",-1);                  // empty Source String
r |= test("","",-1);                  // empty Source String and Look-For String

if (r==0) console.log("✅ All startsWithAr() test cases passed");


//-----------------------------------
function test(str,lookfor,should) {
  let result= startsWithAr(str,lookfor);
  if (result !== should) {console.log(`
  ${str} Output   :${result}
  ${str} Should be:${should}
  `);return 1;}
  }
```

---

## 2nd Part: removeStartString()

---

```js
//=====================================================================
// removeStartString() function
// Purpose:
// Determines whether an Arabic string (the "Source String") begins with the characters
// of a specified string (the "Look-For String").
// If found the Look-For String is removed and the reminder of the Source String is returned
// with its original Tashkeel (diacritics);
// If no match then return original Source String.
//
// Ignores Tashkeel (diacritics) and Tahmeez in both the Source and Look-For Strings.
// The function uses the startsWithAr() function to determine the index after the matched
// starting string/characters.
//
// Parameters:
// str     : The Source String to search in.
// toRemove: The characters to be searched for and removed if at the start of this string.
//=====================================================================
function removeStartString(str,toRemove) {
let index=startsWithAr(str,toRemove);
if (index>-1) str=str.slice(index);
return str;
}

//=========================================
// test cases for removeStartString() function
//=========================================
var r =0; // test tracking flag
r |= test2("السلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","السلام"," عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله");  // remove the start letters 'السلام'
r |= test2("ألْسًّلامُ عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","السلام"," عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله");  // remove the start letters 'ألْسًّلامُ'
r |= test2("السلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","ألْسًّلامُ"," عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله");  // remove the start letters 'ألْسًّلامُ'
r |= test2(" السلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله"," ألْسًّلامُ"," عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله");// remove the start letters 'ألْسًّلامُ '
r |= test2("السلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله","ال","سلام عَلَيَكُمُ ورحمة الله"); // remove the start letters 'ال'
r |= test2("أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا","ا","هْلًا وَسَهلًا");             // remove the start letter 'ا'    r |= test2("أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا"," ","أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا");                // remove the start letter ' '
r |= test2("أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا","","أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا");             // remove the start letter ''
r |= test2("أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا","إلى","أَهْلًا وَسَهلًا");           // remove the start letters 'إلى'

if (r==0) console.log("✅ All removeStartString() test cases passed");

//-----------------------------------
function startsWithAr(str,lookFor) {
let indexLookFor=0, tshk=/[ؐ-ًؕ-ٖٓ-ٟۖ-ٰٰۭـ]/, w=/[ؤ]/g,hamz=/[آأإٱٲٳٵ]/g;
lookFor=lookFor.replace(hamz,'ا').replace(w,'و').replace(/[ؐ-ًؕ-ٖٓ-ٟۖ-ٰٰۭـ]/g,''); 
for (let indexStr=0; indexStr<str.length;indexStr++) {
while(tshk.test(str[indexStr])&&indexStr<str.length)++indexStr; 
if (lookFor[indexLookFor]!==str[indexStr].replace(hamz,'ا').replace(w,'و')) return-1;
indexLookFor++;                                           
    if (indexLookFor>=lookFor.length) {                    
      indexStr+=1;                                         
      while(tshk.test(str[indexStr])&&indexStr<str.length)++indexStr; 
    return indexStr;
    }
}
return-1;
}
//-----------------------------------
function test2(str,toRemove,should) {
  let result= removeStartString(str,toRemove);
  if (result !== should) {console.log(`
  ${str} Output   :${result}
  ${str} Should be:${should}
  `);return 1;}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with [*regex unicode escapes*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) might already be good enough for what the OP is looking for, though JavaScript does not support [*unicode scripts*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script) like `\p{Arabic}`.

A category based pattern like [`/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+\p{Z}+/gmu`](https://regex101.com/r/1l5TYw/1) together with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) already exactly does what the OP did ask for ...

> *find and remove first starting word from an arabic string having diacritis*

The pattern ... `^[\p{L}\p{M}]+\p{Z}+` ... reads like this ...

- `^`... starting at the beginning of a new line ...
- `[ ... ]+` ... find at list one character of the specified character class ...

  - `\p{L}` ... either any kind of `L`etter from any language,
  - `\p{M}` ... or a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)
- ... followed by `\p{Z}+` ... at least one of any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

```js
console.log(`السلام عليكم ورحمة الله
السَلام عليكمُ ورحمةُ الله
السَلامُ عَليكمُ ورَحمةُ الله
السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`.replace(/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+\p{Z}+/gmu, ''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

Since it is clear now what the OP really wants, the above approach remains and just gets raised to the next level by utilizing a [`replacer` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#parameters) with additional comparison logic based on an [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) object which [takes Arabic and base letter comparison into account](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#parameters).

The collator is initialized the least strict by providing (additionally to the `'ar'` locals) an option which features a *base sensitivity*. Thus, while comparing two similar (but not quite equal) strings via the collator's [`compare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare) method, e.g. `'السلام'` and `'السَّلَامُ'` will be considered equal despite of the latter featuring (a lot of) diacritics.

proof / examples ...

```js
const baseLetterCollator = new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } );

console.log(
  "('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' === 'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله') ?..",
  ('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' === 'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله')
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(`new Intl.Collator()
  .compare('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' ,'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله') === 0

  ?..`,
  new Intl.Collator()
    .compare('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' ,'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله') === 0
);
console.log(`new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } )
  .compare('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' ,'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله') === 0

  ?..`,
  new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } )
    .compare('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله' ,'السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله') === 0
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Based on all the above said ... the final solution ...

```js
function removeFirstMatchingWordFromEveryNewLine(search, multilineString) {
  const baseLetterCollator
    // - [ar]abic
    // - base sensitivity
    //   ... only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal.
    = new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } );

  const replacer = word => {
    return (baseLetterCollator.compare(search, word.trim()) === 0)
      ? ''    // - remove the matching word (whitespace included).
      : word; // - keep the word since there was no match. 
  }
  const regXFirstLineWord = /^[\p{L}\p{M}]+\p{Z}+/gmu;

  search = String(search).trim();

  return String(multilineString).replace(regXFirstLineWord, replacer);  
}
const sampleData = `السلام عليكم ورحمة الله
السَلام عليكمُ ورحمةُ الله
أهلا ومرحبا
السَلامُ عَليكمُ ورَحمةُ الله
السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`;

console.log('sampleData ...', sampleData);
console.log(
  "removeFirstMatchingWordFromEveryNewLine('السلام', sampleData) ...",
  removeFirstMatchingWordFromEveryNewLine('السلام', sampleData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What will be the output if the string was "أهلا ومرحبا"? Will it not find the word we are looking for "السلام"? and return the original string in this case?

Comment: We need to remove the starting string/word if it matches the word/string we specify. i.e. not just remove whatever the first/starting word is. In this case, we are looking for the word "السلام"; but could be any other word. If, there is a match then remove it; else returnn the original string.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't get this from the original question. Then things are still solvable, but do need a little bit more work by utilizing e.g. [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator). Thus one question is ... how does one initially get the word which then everything needs to be matched/compared against?

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei ... done. Have a look into the above final solution.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the `Intl.Collator`. This is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since requirements change(d) and information come in slice by slice, ...

> *"The [...] answer removes the first matching word assuming a space after the word. But the string of characters we are looking for may not necessarily be followed by a space (i.e. not a standalone word). For example, removing the characters "السيد" from the sentence "السيد/محسن اليافعي" and returning only "/محسن اليافعي". –
> Mohsen Alyafei"*

... I also will start at a blank sheet.

The combined approach of doing a [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) based locale [`compare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare) against the matching result of a [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) based regex which matches any Arabic **word** regardless of combined characters like accents, umlauts, etc. can not be used anymore if it comes to finding/matching any kind of string (and here in the beginning of a new line).

But any approach which tries to just naively iterate over strings with the intention of comparing two strings to one another character by character will fail.

Example code tells better than words ... let's see it ...

```js
console.log(`
  ... remember ...
  new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } )
    .compare('السَّلَامُ' ,'السلام') === 0

  ?..`, new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } )
    .compare('السَّلَامُ' ,'السلام') === 0, `

  ... but ...
  new Intl.Collator('ar')
    .compare('السَّلَامُ' ,'السلام') === 0

  ?..`, new Intl.Collator('ar')
    .compare('السَّلَامُ' ,'السلام') === 0
);
console.log('\n... explanation ...\n\n');

console.log("'السلام'.length ...", 'السلام'.length);
console.log("'السَّلَامُ'.length ...", 'السَّلَامُ'.length);

console.log("'السلام'.split('') ...", 'السلام'.split(''));
console.log("'السَّلَامُ'.split('') ...", 'السَّلَامُ'.split(''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Fortunately [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), ECMAScript's Internationalization API, can help here too. There is [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) which will help breaking down the string(s) into comparable segments. For the OP's use case it will be good enough to do it on [the default `granularity` level of `'grapheme'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter/Segmenter#parameters), which seems to equal a *segmentation into **locale comparable** letters* ...

```js
console.log(`[
  ...new Intl.Segmenter('ar', { granularity: 'grapheme' }).segment('السلام')
]
.map(({ segment }) => segment) ...`, [

  ...new Intl.Segmenter('ar', { granularity: 'grapheme' }).segment('السلام')
  ]
  .map(({ segment }) => segment)
);
console.log(`[
  ...new Intl.Segmenter('ar').segment('السَّلَامُ')
]
.map(({ segment }) => segment) ...`, [

    ...new Intl.Segmenter('ar').segment('السَّلَامُ')
  ]
  .map(({ segment }) => segment)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Thus the last step was to implement a function which meets the most recent requirements of the OP by combining the above introduced `Intl.Segmenter` with the by now already familiar `Intl.Collator` ...

```js
function removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart(search, multilineString) {
  const letterSegmenter
    // - [ar]abic
    // - default grapheme granularity (locale comparable letters).
    = new Intl.Segmenter('ar'/*, { granularity: 'grapheme' }*/);

  const letterCollator
    // - [ar]abic
    // - base sensitivity
    //   ... Non-zero comparator result value for strings only
    //   that for a base letter comparison are considered unequal.
    = new Intl.Collator('ar', { sensitivity: 'base' } );

  const getLocaleComparableLetterList = str =>
    [...letterSegmenter.segment(str)].map(({ segment }) => segment);

  function replaceLineStartByBoundComparableLetters(line) {
    const searchLetters = this;
    let lineLetters = getLocaleComparableLetterList(line);

    if (searchLetters.every((searchLetter, idx/*, arr*/) =>
      (letterCollator.compare(searchLetter, lineLetters[idx]) === 0)
    )) {
      lineLetters = lineLetters.slice(searchLetters.length);

      let leadingBlanks = '';
      while (lineLetters[0] === ' ') {
        leadingBlanks = leadingBlanks + lineLetters.shift();
      }
      line = `${ lineLetters.join('') }${ leadingBlanks }`;

      // // due to keeping/restoring leading witespace sequences ...
      // // ... all the above additional computation instead of ...
      // // ... a simple ...
      // line = lineLetters.slice(searchLetters.length).join('')
    }
    return line;
  }
  return String(multilineString)
    .split(/(\n)/)
    .map(
      replaceLineStartByBoundComparableLetters.bind(
        getLocaleComparableLetterList(String(search))
      )
    )
    .join('');
}
const sampleData = `السلام عليكم ورحمة الله
السَلام عليكمُ ورحمةُ الله
أهلا ومرحبا
السَلامُ عَليكمُ ورَحمةُ الله
السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`;

console.log('sampleData ...', sampleData);
console.log(
  "removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('السلام', sampleData) ...",
  removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('السلام', sampleData)
);
console.log(
  "removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('الس', sampleData) ...",
  removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('الس', sampleData)
);
console.log(
  "removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('السلام ', sampleData) ...",
  removeEveryMatchingNewLineStart('السلام ', sampleData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei ... have a look at this new implementation which takes the most recent requirements into account and is capable of operating the search and replace task on multiline strings regardless of whatever the search string will be (including leading/trailing whitespace(s))

Comment: I have added a possible additional solution.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei ... saw it. nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what wrong in your code, but here is another approach:

```js
function removeStartWord(string, word) {
  return string.split(' ').filter((_word, index) => index !== 0 || _word.replace(/[^a-zA-Zء-ي]+/g, '') !== word).join(' ');
}

const sampleData = `السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`;

console.log('sampleData ...', sampleData);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'الس') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'الس')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام ') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, 'السلام ')
);
console.log(
  "removeStartWord(sampleData, ' السلام') ...",
  removeStartWord(sampleData, ' السلام')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The above code will always remove the first word from any string irrespective of the word. We need to first find the word and only remove it if it is the word we are looking for.

Comment: it remove the given word only if it is the first, I update it, did you try it ?

Comment: Yes. Tried : `console.log(removeStartWord("السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله","السلام"));`. The output that it could not remove it and returned: `السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ وَرَحْمَةُ الله`. i.e. the original string.

Comment: understood, interesting, will think about it

Comment: Great Jafar. Thanks

Comment: updated my answer, check it now please!

Comment: The above answer removes the first matching word assuming a space after the word. But the string of characters we are looking for may not necessarily be followed by a space (i.e. not a standalone word). For example, removing the characters "السيد" from the sentence "السيد/محسن اليافعي" and returning only "/محسن اليافعي".

Comment: nice, wait for update please

Comment: @JafarJabr I have added an example table image for better clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

I have created an npm package that addresses this issue and more, All you have to do is

```
npm install arabic-utils
```

then in your code you can do something like this:

```
import ArabicString from "arabic-utils";

console.log(ArabicString("السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ").remove("السلام")) // " عَلَيْكُمُ"
```

If you want to make sure that the text only exists at the beginning of the string you can do this

```
if (ArabicString(originalText).startsWith(stringToRemove)) {
  // Your code here
}
```

Also keep in mind that the package doesn't normalize the token string so you may want to remove diacritics from it before using it with **startsWith** and **remove** methods

```
const normalizedToken = ArabicString("السَّلَامُ").removeDiacritics(); // => "السلام"
```

The package repository **https://github.com/justgo97/arabic-utils**

If you don't want to use a package for some reason then this is the needed code to do it

Let's assume we have these two strings

```
const inputText = "السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ";
const textToRemove = "السلام";
```

we will need a function to remove diacritics because we will use it to get the skeleton of the orginal text, This is the one I personally use but you could use a different method depending on your needs

```
const commonArabicDiacritics = {
  kasra: { value: " ِ" }, //  ِ Arabic kasra - Garshuni: i
  shadda: { value: " ّ" }, //  ّ Arabic shadda - Garshuni
  sukun: { value: " ْ" }, //  ْ Arabic sukun

  fathatan: { value: " ً" }, //  ً Arabic fathatan - Garshuni: an
  kasratan: { value: " ٍ" }, //  ٍ Arabic kasratan - Garshuni: in
  dammatan: { value: " ٌ" }, //  ٌ Arabic dammatan - Garshuni: un
  fatha: { value: " َ" }, //  َ Arabic fatha - Garshuni: a
  damma: { value: " ُ" }, //  ُ Arabic damma - Garshuni: u
};

export const arabicSymbolsArray = Object.values(commonArabicDiacritics).map(
  (symbol) => symbol.value.trim()
);

function removeDiacritics(arabicText){
  return arabicText
    .split("")
    .filter((char) => !arabicSymbolsArray.includes(char))
    .join("");
}
```

then we will need a function to split the original string into an array of letters with their respective diacritics so we can match it to the length of the string we stripped diacritics from

```
const validArabicLetters = [
  "ا",
  "أ",
  "إ",
  "آ",
  "ب",
  "ت",
  "ث",
  "ج",
  "ح",
  "خ",
  "د",
  "ذ",
  "ر",
  "ز",
  "س",
  "ش",
  "ص",
  "ض",
  "ط",
  "ظ",
  "ع",
  "غ",
  "ف",
  "ق",
  "ك",
  "ل",
  "م",
  "ن",
  "ه",
  "و",
  "ي",
  "ى",
  "ة",
  "ء",
  "ؤ",
  "ئ",
];

function isStringEmpty(str) {
  return str.trim().length === 0;
}

function splitArabicLetters(arabicText) {
  const result = [];

  for (const char of arabicText) {
    if (!isStringEmpty(char) && !validArabicLetters.includes(char)) {
      result[result.length - 1] += char;
    } else {
      result.push(char);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now that we have these functions we can create our **removeFromStart** function

```
const removeFromStart(arabicText, textToRemove) {
  const normalizedText = removeDiacritics(arabicText);

  // Check if the text to remove exists at the start
  if (!normalizedText.startsWith(textToRemove)) {
    // If not found, return the original string
    return arabicText;
  }

  // Find the starting index of the text to remove in the normalized text
  const startIdx = normalizedText.indexOf(textToRemove);

  // Split the original Arabic text into separate letters
  const textSeparated = splitArabicLetters(arabicText);

  // Remove the specified text from the array using splice
  textSeparated.splice(startIdx, textToRemove.length);

  // Join the modified array elements to get the resulting string
  const result = textSeparated.join("");

  // Return the modified string
  return result;
}
```

And that's it

```
const inputText = "السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمُ";
const textToRemove = "السلام";

const commonArabicDiacritics = {
  kasra: { value: " ِ" }, //  ِ Arabic kasra - Garshuni: i
  shadda: { value: " ّ" }, //  ّ Arabic shadda - Garshuni
  sukun: { value: " ْ" }, //  ْ Arabic sukun

  fathatan: { value: " ً" }, //  ً Arabic fathatan - Garshuni: an
  kasratan: { value: " ٍ" }, //  ٍ Arabic kasratan - Garshuni: in
  dammatan: { value: " ٌ" }, //  ٌ Arabic dammatan - Garshuni: un
  fatha: { value: " َ" }, //  َ Arabic fatha - Garshuni: a
  damma: { value: " ُ" }, //  ُ Arabic damma - Garshuni: u
};

const arabicSymbolsArray = Object.values(commonArabicDiacritics).map(
  (symbol) => symbol.value.trim()
);

function removeDiacritics(arabicText){
  return arabicText
    .split("")
    .filter((char) => !arabicSymbolsArray.includes(char))
    .join("");
}

const validArabicLetters = [
  "ا",
  "أ",
  "إ",
  "آ",
  "ب",
  "ت",
  "ث",
  "ج",
  "ح",
  "خ",
  "د",
  "ذ",
  "ر",
  "ز",
  "س",
  "ش",
  "ص",
  "ض",
  "ط",
  "ظ",
  "ع",
  "غ",
  "ف",
  "ق",
  "ك",
  "ل",
  "م",
  "ن",
  "ه",
  "و",
  "ي",
  "ى",
  "ة",
  "ء",
  "ؤ",
  "ئ",
];

function isStringEmpty(str) {
  return str.trim().length === 0;
}

function splitArabicLetters(arabicText) {
  const result = [];

  for (const char of arabicText) {
    if (!isStringEmpty(char) && !validArabicLetters.includes(char)) {
      result[result.length - 1] += char;
    } else {
      result.push(char);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function removeFromStart(arabicText, textToRemove) {
  const normalizedText = removeDiacritics(arabicText);

  // Check if the text to remove exists at the start
  if (!normalizedText.startsWith(textToRemove)) {
    // If not found, return the original string
    return arabicText;
  }

  // Find the starting index of the text to remove in the normalized text
  const startIdx = normalizedText.indexOf(textToRemove);

  // Split the original Arabic text into separate letters
  const textSeparated = splitArabicLetters(arabicText);

  // Remove the specified text from the array using splice
  textSeparated.splice(startIdx, textToRemove.length);

  // Join the modified array elements to get the resulting string
  const result = textSeparated.join("");

  // Return the modified string
  return result;
}

console.log(removeFromStart(inputText, textToRemove)) // " عَلَيْكُمُ"
```